# Python plot in tmux session not showing

Tags: python, matplotlib, tmux

When using tmux on the local machine (mac) and doing `plt.show()`, the window does not show up. But the code can be run and a figure can be saved. Meanwhile, a x-window can be open on the same session.

I have test it on iterm2 and the native terminal on mac. It gives me the same behavior. Do we need some extra configurations to display the plots on tmux?

Comment: Does invoking this magical incantation before running the python script solve the issue? `export DISPLAY="\`tmux show-env | sed -n 's/^DISPLAY=//p'\`"`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Paul. No, it did not help. BTW, ```DISPLAY``` becomes ```/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.k7zDOlgpLB/org.macosforge.xquartz:0``` after export.

Comment: Sorry to hear; updating the display variable usually does the trick for me, albeit on a linux server, not MacOS. What backend are you using (`matplotlib.get_backend()`)? Are there no error messages or warnings whatsoever? Also, you might have more luck asking on https://superuser.com.

Comment: There is also https://apple.stackexchange.com/, which I didn't even know existed until just now.

Comment: I think I figure out why. It was due to PATH issue. It pick up an old system python (2.7). Thanks again, Paul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because my PATH got messed up due to the reason given in https://superuser.com/questions/544989/does-tmux-sort-the-path-variable

It picked up the old python2.7 in `/usr/bin/python` because tmux called `/etc/profile` and add system bins in the front of my shell PATH.

To fix it, this trick works for me

```
if [ -f /etc/profile ]; then
    PATH=""
    source /etc/profile
fi
```